# Change UrlZone of KeywordQuery

Tags: 2010, search, web-application-zones

I'm trying to perform searches programmatically for the backend of a web part, but all the results are from the default zone. I want them to come from the same zone as the SPSite object I'm using as a context for the search, but the UrlZone property of KeywordQuery is read only.

Is it possible to change the UrlZone of a KeywordQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I managed to miss something in my own code. KeywordQuery seems to use the urlzone of whatever it's given in the constructor. I grabbed the current serviceContext which did not contain a proper zone declaration so it used the default zone. Switching to the current SPSite object (which *did* have the correct zone) solved the issue.